# JSF2 Extract URL Parameter

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using primefaces menubar and, depending on the selected menuitem I would like to pass a diferent parameter in the URL (GET)

```
<ui:composition>
    <h:form rendered="#{facesContext.externalContext.userPrincipal != null}">
        <p:menubar>
            <p:menuitem value="#{msg['menu.home']}" url="/index.xhtml" />
            <p:submenu label="#{msg['menu.maintenance']}" >
                <p:menuitem id="client" value="#{msg['menu.clients']}" action="/person/newPerson?faces-redirect=true" ajax="false" includeViewParams="true">
                     **<f:param name="type" value="client"/>**
                </p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem id="supplier" value="#{msg['menu.suppliers']}" action="/person/newPerson?faces-redirect=true" ajax="false" >
                    **<f:param name="type" value="supplier"/>**
                </p:menuitem>
            </p:submenu>
```

This way when the menuitem "client" is selected I would like to use the GET parameter "type=client" in the newPerson.xhtml like so:

```
<h:outputText value="Parameter: #{param['type']}" />
```

However, no parameter is being passed in the URL. Can someone tell me what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of action attribute try URL

```
<p:menuitem id="client" value="#{msg['menu.clients']}" url="/person/newPerson?faces-redirect=true&type=client" ajax="false" includeViewParams="true">
</p:menuitem>
```